# godot make Physics2dServer visible in game

Tags: godot, gdscript

**this is my example code i also have Debug (visible collision shapes on) and I still can't see anything in game, my goal is to add a circle collision shape and be able to see in game**

```
func create_area(mouse_position):
    var position = mouse_position

    var _shared_Area = Area2D.new()
    var _circle_shape = Physics2DServer.circle_shape_create()

    #_circle_shape.visible = true

    Physics2DServer.shape_set_data(_circle_shape, 128)

    print(" physics server ",Physics2DServer.ray_shape_create())
   
    Physics2DServer.area_add_shape(_shared_Area.get_rid(), _circle_shape, xform )
    Physics2DServer.area_set_collision_layer(_shared_Area, 1)
    Physics2DServer.area_set_collision_mask(_shared_Area, 1)
    Physics2DServer.area_set_monitorable(_shared_Area, true)
    Physics2DServer.area_set_space(_shared_Area, get_world_2d().space)


    Physics2DServer.area_set_transform(_shared_Area, Transform2D(1.0 , position))
    Physics2DServer.area_set_area_monitor_callback(_shared_Area, self, 'debug_overlap')


func debug_overlap(_1,_2,_3,_4,_5):
    print('overlap!!')
```

Comment: The `Physics2DServer` only deals with physics, as it should. The logic to draw those debug shapes in the nodes. So... You are going to have draw your own debug shapes. Edit: perhaps you would be interested in the `VisualServer`.

Comment: i guess that would be my only option i also read the Godot Api for phsics2dserver about making it visible but nothing